# site to site openVpn link aggregation with linux

Tags: linux, openvpn, linux-networking, bonding

I'm trying to improve access over VPN for a site office to the head office.
Will the following increase **single file** download speed.

Provide 2 WAN (NBN) connection at both sites.
Dedicate each WAN link to an openVpn tunnel for a total of two seperate VPN links.
Bond the tun interfaces using round robin at both ends to form a single ip interface.